# Use onSubmit to setState for the multiple inputs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to take the data from these two inputs within my form and set one as state.name, and the other as state.option. Is there a way to set them upon using the form submit button rather than using individual onChange handlers to set each of those states? If not, it feels awkward having a submit button that doesn't really do anything.

```
   onTextChange(name) {
                this.setState({ name });
                console.log(this.state.name);
            }
            onOptionChange(option) {
                this.setState({ realm });
                console.log(this.state.option);
            }
            onSubmitForm(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h3>Enter Name:</h3>
                        <form onSubmit={event => this.onSubmitForm(event.target.value)}>
                            <input 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Name"
                            value={this.state.name}
                            onChange={event => this.onTextChange(event.target.value)}
                            />
                   Select Option:
                        <select onChange = {event => this.onOptionChange(event.target.value)}>
                                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Then drop the submit button. The short answer is you shouldn't do it. The long one is that if there is a way to get the input values from the submit event, it would be cumbersome and brittle, and you would have to pick apart the SyntheticEvent, which could break your app if you ever update react and they change its internal representation. My advice is go for the simple solution and use onChange handlers, that guarantees that your state is consistent and predictable, which is the main benefit of a framework like react

Comment: Good to know. So I will be using the inputs as parameters for an API request in the parent function. Will this get sloppy that way? Or will it be ok with some error handling, like a loading bar until both inputs are selected.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean. Typically what you would do is use the onSubmit handler to send the request, and take the parameters you need from the data you stored in state. There you get the chance to check for errors before sending the request. You can also do something like `this.setState({ loading: true })` before firing the request, and render a loader accordingly. The individual onChange handlers give you the chance to validate each input as it is changed

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. So in the onSubmit function I would run my function in the parent component that uses these child component state pieces as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In React, you have to control what happens in form/input in state and `setState` to change it. That's call [Single source of truth](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Welcome to React :)